# SQL Query Find differences in rows in one table

Tags: sql, sqlite, foreign-keys, self-join

assume I have the following table:

```
ID | CMP1 | CMP2 | CMP3 | FK1
------------------------------
1  |   x  |   x  |   x  | 1
2  |   y  |   y  |   y  | 1
3  |   z  |   z  |   z  | 1
------------------------------
4  |   a  |   a  |   a  | 2
5  |   a  |   a  |   a  | 2
6  |   c  |   c  |   c  | 2
------------------------------
7  |   s  |   u  |   v  | 3
8  |   s  |   u  |   i  | 3
9  |   s  |   u  |   z  | 3
```

Now I have to write a query that returns all IDs that are referenced by FK1 but have different values in CMP1-3.

Example:

- For ID 1-3, the query must return 1,2,3.
- For ID 4-6, the query must return 6.
- For ID 7-9, the query must return 7,8,9.

I know that I have to self-join the table, but i cannot compare the values grouped by FK1 - Please help!

Thanks

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want rows where the value of (cmp1, cmp2, cmp3, fk1) is unique.  YOu can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by cmp1, cmp2, cmp3, fk1) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt = 1;
```

An alternative method uses `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.fk1 = t.fk1 and
                        t2.cmp1 = t.cmp1 and
                        t2.cmp2 = t.cmp2 and
                        t2.cmp3 = t.cmp3 and
                        t2.id <> t.id
                 );
```

That is, no other row exists with the same `(fk1, cmp1, cmp2, cmp3)` combination -- and a different `id`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. However, its more like the combination of cmp1, cmp2, cmp3 and fk1 that has to be unique. Is it possible to use it like this: (partition by cmp1, cmp2, cmp3, fk1)?

Comment: @JohnniO. . . . I see.  That is what `cmp1-3` means.  I updated the answer.